# Disable scrolling when menu is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a full screen menu, and I managed to have the block of a `width: 100%;` and `min-height: 100%;`. Now my page is a bit longer so when I scroll down, I see the full screen menu, does not apply for the rest of the page.

`nav` block is outside the `container`

```
<nav id="site-nav" class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item"><a href="#">UI/UX Designer</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Front-End DEV</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- end .menu-wrap -->
```

CSS:

```
#site-nav {
    display: none;
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Is there a way to disable scrolling when this menu is triggered? Or some CSS trick?

Note:
As a final result, I want the body to be 100%, only when the menu block is triggered. Any solutions for that?

Comment: This trick with `position: fixed;` works ok, but not as I wanted, I tried as well to give body `overflow: hidden` and `max-width: 100%;` but I still have the scroll. So the issue remains. Maybe any JS solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to disable scrolling is to just use `overflow: hidden;` on the element that should not contain scroll (it can be body tag).

But in this case I propose to set `position: fixed;` instead of absolute and than your menu will be always fullscreen (but it will not hide scrollbar). It is totally the simplest way, and will not cause problems as body with `overflow:hidden;` and `max-width: 100%;` can do.

Comment: This trick with `position: fixed;` works ok, but not as I wanted, I tried as well to give body `overflow: hidden` and `max-width: 100%;` but I still have the scroll. So the issue remains. Maybe any JS solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Set the body,html max-height to 100%, and overflow: hidden;

HTML:

```
<nav id="site-nav" class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item"><a href="#">UI/UX Designer</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Front-End DEV</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- end .menu-wrap -->
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#site-nav {
    display: none;
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This would block the scrolling for my entire website, but what I want is to make it happen only the menu block is triggered.